# Downloading file with progress. Is this the right way of doing it?

Tags: android, inputstream

Is there a more efficent way of doing this in terms of memory usage
and performance. The following method downloads a bitmap and calls
a function with the progress.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            if(imageInterface != null) {
                imageInterface.duringDownload(
                        imageView, ((int)total * 100 / fileLength));
            }
            outputStream.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        input.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        return bitmap;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your time consuming tasks should not run on UI thread. Use an `AsyncTask` and update the UI from on `onProgressUpdate` method.

Increase your bucket size. At the moment you read 1024 byte chunks at a time and update UI after each read. For example for a 1MB image you refresh your UI 1024 times. This is inefficient, so if you increase buffer size you need to do less UI refreshes:

```
byte data[] = new byte[100 * 1024];
```

Comment: hmm, I don't see the difference between running it directly on the UI thread (imageInterface), instead of indirectly via onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I believe your method is error prone to **OutOfMemoryException** if it will try to load a large image. To fix this you'll need to scale down the bitmap before assigning it in memory.

Read this article if you are really concerned about efficiency: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to the example given in the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

  // Do not update UI here, only do downloading in background.
  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    while (...) {
      // do input.read() and outputStream.write() just like in your original code

      // Use AsyncTask method to publish progress
      publishProgress((int)total * 100 / fileLength);
    }
  }

 // Here is where you use the progress value to update UI.
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     imageInterface.duringDownload(
         imageView, progress[0]);

 }
}
```